# Moving between cells based on checkbox status

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to generate a unique output when a button is clicked on one sheet that will depend on the state of a group of check boxes.

There is a group of ten boxes, any of which can be selected for a maximum of ten. When the button is clicked, the name of each check box will appear sequentially. So for example:

Check box 1 and 3 are checked, the button is clicked, then the output to the cells will look like: [Check Box1] [Check Box3]

However if boxes 1 2 3 9 are checked, it will display:
[Check Box1] [Check Box2] [Check Box3] etc....

My main issue is that I only want the name of the checkbox to appear as a heading if it is selected.

Comment: A heading of what???

Comment: The heading will be the name of the checkbox that was selected

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "forms" checkboxes (vs. ActiveX type)

```
dim i, n, s

n = 0
for i = 1 to 10
    s = "Check Box " & i
    if activesheet.checkboxes(s).Value = 1 then
        Activesheet.range("A1").offset(0, n).value = s
        n = n + 1
    end if
next i
```

Comment: Sorry should have specified, I would need it for ActiveX type